# Codeigniter function data that will not show undefined variable error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want build a function in Codeigniter that will not show undefined variable error on view page, if variable is not set than no error or if variable is set then print same value.

I write this following function but this function not working.

```
    if (!function_exists('_e')) {
     function _e( $data ) {
      if(!isset($data))
        return false;
      else
        echo $data;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you wanna use this function in your view file ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Like <?php _e($variable) ?> if variable is set then echo that particular variable if not then echo nothing not even error

Comment: Have you tested it with `var_dump(_e($variable))`?

Comment: @Tpojka yes I tried same. I got 'Null'

Comment: Where did you write that function? is that some custom helper? How did you load it? Where do you call that part of code? Is there some code execution after that line? After answering to these questions try with hard coded string too: `var_dump(_e('some string'))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!function_exists('_e')) {
     function _e( $data ) {
      if(!isset($data))
        return "";
      else
        return $data;
      }
    }
```

This should help you out.

Comment: No :(  got same error "Message: Undefined variable: $variable"

Comment: I think this approach will not work because before the variable gets passed to the function, it will throw the error. So the function won't be called even.

Comment: do one thing before function calling place a isset checking against variable.

Comment: @molagbal Sonu is trying to define a global function which can be used instead isset function for each variables in view file of Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!function_exists('_e')) {
function _e( $variable ) {

     /*do anything to set $data if you want example below */
     $data = str_replace('WTF', 'WTH' $variable); //<< example 

      if(!isset($data)){
        return false;
      }else{
        return $data;
      }
 }
 }
```

dont forget to set your variable first. then you can try to echo or print_r for test.

example

```
<?php
$variable = 'this is WTF';
print_r( _e($variable) ); // << print_r for testing, or use echo _e($data);
?>
```

notes: if your file is in other php file. dont forget to call file first.